# How to use the Dropbox Camera Uploads only for new pictures I take

Tags: android, dropbox, upload

I need to quickly start uploading new pictures I take on my Android device to Dropbox, and for efficiency purposes I need it to automatically upload as soon as I take the picture.  However, as soon as I turn on Camera Uploads I see pictures start appearing on my PC in my Dropbox folder, even though I have not taken any pictures yet.  It appears that Dropbox is uploading pictures I have already taken!   Strangely, there isn't even any indication on the Android device that this is happening.

This behavior is unacceptable for two reasons:  first, I have a LOT of pictures I have already taken, and I cannot wait for them all the upload before I can start getting new pictures off the camera.  Second, I probably don't even have enough space in Dropbox and it is going to use up my quota before I even have a chance to get to new pictures that I actually want to upload.

How can I tell or trick Dropbox into not uploading any pictures already on the camera?

Comment: It doesn't look like you can. You should be able to delete the old photos out of your Dropbox storage, though; it's pretty smart about not re-uploading stuff.

Comment: Thanks, this was the route I eventually took, although I did have to periodically delete the old ones of the computer to prevent it from using up my quota.  It appears Dropbox does give some priority to uploading new pictures before old ones so it wasn't quite as much a pain as I had imagined.